# Making Input Element Style same with class

Tags: css

I know my title is a little bit weird. I'm trying to add a  specific class to an input without directly adding the class name to it. Example:

I want `.add` CSS to be same with `input[type="text"]`. This is my code:

```
<style> input[type="file"] .add{background-color: #f7f7f7;} </style>

<input type="text"/>
```

I want the `.add` class to automatically apply to it; how do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to add a class in the input box but not directly.

Then Use JQuery

```
 $(function() {
  $('input').addClass('add');
});
```

Here is a [jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/qy94tnc1/) I made..

Comment: Wow! Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks Shadow, Good Job!

Comment: @MosesOsasotaIribhogbe I'm glad I was able to help :)

Answer (score 0):

The HTML:

```
<input type="file">
```

And you can try the following css:

```
input[type="file"] {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a class in CSS

```
.add{
   background:orange;
   // your css goes here
 }
```

and in your HTML you have to add  the class

```
<input type="text" class="add">
```

make sure that your CSS file is linked.

Comment: this will also work the same...If you don't want this you can give an another class on input and copy the same CSS